# What does "I'm really into it" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What does the phrase

> I'm really into it.

mean?

I think it means the same thing as "I really like it." Is that correct? Why not just say that? Is there a difference in meaning?

Comment: **"I'm really into" = "I'm really interested in"**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phrase "I'm really into it" means that the speaker is very interested in the subject or activity he or she is talking about. Here's an example.

> I have been playing football for ten years. I am really into it.
>
> I am watching a film about World War II. I am really into it.

Also, you haven't provided any context in your question so there is a possibility the phrase could mean something else in your case.

Answer (score 0):

***[Be into](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/be-into)*** also, ***get into:***

> - Be interested in or involved with:
>
>   - For example, *She's really into yoga, or Once you retire, it's important to get into some hobby you've always wanted to try.* ( mid-1900s)

Your dictionary.com